# installing old version of java

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, java

I need to install java 1.0.8_45 for some program I'm using (cubemx)

my closest attempt was installing from [here](https://www.filepuma.com/download/java_runtime_environment_64bit_-296/versions/2) but when I tried to install it show me code error 1627

if it matter i have succeed to install the last version of java with

> apt install default-jre

google didn't help so I'm hoping maybe you know how to do it

BTW I'm using Ubuntu 20.4

Comment: because when I'm installing cubemx, its ask for for this. do you know of away to avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

Some older versions of a packages are still available on repositories. You can check them by using Synaptic (package>force version).
If you didn't find what you want, you can also [check here](http://snapshot.debian.org/) to look for some old Debian packages. You should probably install what you want manually.

Comment: the version I'm looking for (8u45) is not there, at least not that I could find. but mayby its just because its day 1 for me with ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

If it is STM32CubeMX that you want to install, here is what you can do:

Since Oracle does not allow downloading its binaries anymore without a user account, you need an alternative. I use Azul Systems OpenJDK successfully following [this](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/04/install-latest-openjdk-12-11-or-8-in.html)  guide since Oracle Java does not work anymore. They have several older versions available for installation, including zulu-8 which corresponds to Java 8. This works fine with STM32CubeMX.